# Django filter get at least n records

Tags: django, django-filter

Is there an efficient way to get *at least* n records for a given filter and order? More specifically, I want to get a list of all entries in a model that have a certain date field greater than a month ago, but in case there are less than 10 such entries matching the filter, then get at least 10 of such entries by relaxing the filter. I can do this by getting the count, then checking and making the query again, but was wondering if there was a better way to do it.

Comment: If there's fewer than 10 entries, how do you get at least 10 entries, then? Do you relax the filter or something?

Comment: Yes, relax the filter. By fewer than 10 entries, I meant fewer than 10 matching the filter.

Comment: Relax the filter how, exactly?

Comment: @ubadub as in ignore the filter ...